# WIFI BSSID/MAC Геолокация

Tags: python, api, ip, wifi, mac

Год назад я нашел api от yandex'а с помощью которого можно было узнать местоположение по mac адресу точки доступа WIFI,но сейчас оно не работает,существуют ли РАБОЧИЕ,ПРОВЕРЕННЫЕ аналоги?

Comment: недавно работало. попробуй в другом месте и передать больше bss

Comment: Вы на линуксе или на винде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если я не ошибаюсь то вы говорите об [этом](https://habr.com/ru/post/250267/). Судя по всему это действительно перестало работать... Немного поискав, я [нашел](https://github.com/darkosancanin/apple_bssid_locator) на гитхабе рабочее решение.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Спасибо,это реально работает